# Generating 3D representation of scanned 2D picture of text

Tags: 3d

I want to generate 3D representations of some 2D images of text which can be viewed using realD glasses.  An example image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1ZsU.png).

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080154/how-to-create-3d-images-based-on-2d-images), which is pretty similar to mine, but I only have single shots of these images.  Can someone point me to something that might help me?

Comment: The image you link to appears to have the same number of dimensions as the book in front of me, i.e., two.  What are you planning to have a 3D version look like?

Comment: i want the 3-d version to be giving a perception of depth in each letter ,the flow being the same.The aim is to be able to compare 2 text  images using such a technique.

Comment: I still don't understand.  Do you mean doing something like an [optical diff](http://jargon.net/jargonfile/v/vdiff.html) but with each letter at a different (perceived) height to make spotting differences easier?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try some [stereoscopic image display applications](http://www.geowall.org/software.html#stereo) used by the geowall folks.

Also, have you considered alternately displaying the two images.  This [Blink comparator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_comparator) technique can quickly show differences.  This effect can be seen by clicking back and forth on the *First Image* and *Second Image* links in [your example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBtAk.png).

Comment: thanks for the link of "geowall" project.i have implemented the "Blink Comparator"